# Runtime error in my code

Tags: c, dynamic-programming, memoization

I was trying to implement this problem from SPOJ: http://www.spoj.com/problems/COINS/ using memoization but I keep getting Runtime error and cant figure out why. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
long long int max(long long int a,long long int b)
{
    if(a >= b)
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}
long long int dp[100000];
long long solve(long long int n)
{
    long long ans;
    if(n<=50000)
        return dp[n];
    else
        ans=(n,solve(n/2)+solve(n/3)+solve(n/4));
        return ans;

}
int main()
{
    long long int n;
    int t;

   for(int i = 0;i <=50000;i++)
   {
        dp[i] = max(i,dp[i/2] + dp[i/3] + dp[i/4]);
    }

    while((scanf("%d",&t))>0)
        printf("%lld",solve(n));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your code using a debugger, like gdb?

Comment: as per problem, maximum value of **t**  is 1,000,000,000 which is greater than maximum range of int. try **long** instead of **int** for **t**.

Comment: @MahediSabuj not on a 32-bit system.  Even a signed 32-bit int can handle magnitudes greater than 2,000,000,000.  Hint:  what's 2**31?

Comment: as far i know in c, maximum range for int 2^15-1 and for long 2^31-1, isn't it? @TomKarzes

Comment: @MahediSabuj Typically that's only true for a 16-bit system.  I'm guessing OP is running on a 32- or 64-bit system.  C doesn't define the ranges (it only gives minimum required ranges).  Why don't you try it yourself?  Try looking at `sizeof(int)`.  If it's 4 (or greater), then it should be able to handle +/- 2 billion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few problems:

1. In `solve`, you have `ans = (n,solve(n/2)...);`  The leading `n` has no effect.  Did you intend this to be an argument list to `max`?  If so, you need to add `max`.  Otherwise it's just a comma expression and you might as well remove the leading `n`.
2. In `main`, your initialization of `dp` has a problem.  Consider the first pass through the loop, when `i` is 0.  In this case, `i/2` etc. will also be zero, hence those `dp` values will be undefined.  Try setting `dp[0]` explicitly, outside of the loop, and then start your loop at index `1` instead.
3. When printing the solution in `main`, you probably want to add newling `\n` to the end of your `printf` format string.
4. As noted by others, when calling `solve` from `main`, you are passing `n` rather than `t`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely due to this:

```
while((scanf("%d",&t))>0)
       printf("%lld",solve(n));
```

You are reading `t` but passing `n` which is uninitialized. You probably want to pass `t` to `solve()`:

```
while((scanf("%d",&t))>0)
       printf("%lld",solve(t));
```

Answer (score 1):

Reason you get **Runtime Error**

```
while((scanf("%d",&t))>0)
    printf("%lld",solve(n));
```

Here, You get input in variable `t` but pass variable `n` to `solve` function. Use variable `t` or `n` for both case. It will solve your problem.